# Android: Problems with sending sms programmatically

Tags: java, android, sms, byte

I have strange peoblems with sending-receiving sms messages in Android.

I am using standart methods to do it:

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phone, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

(please, don't say that you are using sendMultipleMessages and all works fine, because there is no difference in these methods thoose can resolve my problem)

Before sending sms I am doing something like this: `byte[] b = message.getBytes();`
And I have got the following:

1. sending bytes from 1st emulator: [85]
   receiving on th 2nd emulator     [85]
2. sending bytes from 1st emulator: [85, 94]
   receiving on th 2nd emulator     [85, 94]
3. sending bytes from 1st emulator: [85, 94, 87]
   receiving on th 2nd emulator     [85, 94]!!!!

In other words, sended bytes and received are different or have one or more mismatches!!!
This is a very simple example, only to show where the bug is.

Can anyone who used sending sms test it and post results on his emulator!?
Is this a problem with emulator?

Comment: Have you added the proper permission to your AndroidManifest.xml -- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SEND_SMS?

Comment: Yes, in other case I could not send and receive my sms

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess:

The default SMS charset is not the full Ascii spectrum.

According to [this](http://www.csoft.co.uk/sms/character_sets/gsm.htm) page the code `94 ('^')` needs to be escaped.